# Why does Pyparsing stop parsing after the first element?

Tags: python, regex, pyparsing

I am working with Boolean strings, and I would like to recursively extract those groups that are prefaced with NOT. For example

```py
'x=5 AND ((x=20) OR NOT (x=10 AND NOT x=20))'
```

The predicates are always some text, an equal sign, and some more text. The result I am looking for is

```py
[['x=10', ['x=20']]]
```

My code is then

```py
import pyparsing as pp

def joinGroup(st, loc, t):
  x = t.asList()[0]

  return [''.join(x)]

x = 'x=5 AND ((x=20) OR NOT (x=10 AND NOT x=20))'
p = pp.Group(pp.Word(pp.alphanums) + '=' + pp.Word(pp.alphanums)).setParseAction(joinGroup)

expr = pp.infixNotation(p, [
                        ('NOT', 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, )
                        ])

result = expr.parseString(x).asList()
```

All I get back is `['x=5']`.

Comment: You did not define 'AND' as a valid operator in your infixNotation method call. Also, change your call to `parseString` to add the `parseAll=True` argument, so that pyparsing will raise an exception if the entire input string is not parsed.

Comment: I want to ignore every operator except NOT, treat them like they weren't even there.

Comment: If you want to parse just NOT operators, then start with test strings "x=5" and "NOT(x=5)".  You can also do hacks like  `x = x.replace("AND", "").replace("OR", "")` before parsing. And add a binary operator using None as the operator expression. But I'm not sure this will be actual forward progress. Still, it may give you more general familiarity with pyparsing.